# Fix uiview position in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiinterfaceorientation

In my app, I want to set the UIView orientation according to home button orientation of iPhone. I done it using following way:

```
/* I handled view orientation in shouldAutorotate method*/
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
            viewForBarButtons.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
            viewForBarButtons.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
            viewForBarButtons.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
        else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
            viewForBarButtons.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
```

where viewForBarButtons is a UIView inside a viewController.

But if I set return Yes instead of return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); then it does not work.

How to resolve this issue. If anyone knows it, then please help me. 
Similar functionality is implemented in LifeCards app. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above method is to decide whether to rotate your view to a particular orientation, when device orientation change.

```
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
```

specifies to support only Portrait orientation.

```
return YES;
```

would support all orientation.

But if you are putting your viewcontroller in a TabBarController then it will rotate only if all viewcontrollers support that specific orientation.

Instead of putting the above code to autoresize the object in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

But you need know one thing, by specifing

> UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin

You are just specifying that view can put as much as space want between object and left margin. But it will keep previous positionson other sides during orientation change, so you might need to phsically change the origin of the object (viewForBarButtons)

**Ok. I guess what you are saying is you want the viewForBarButtons beside the homeButton, and need to position/rotate its subviews accordingly.**

First register for devie rotaion or use didRotateInterfaceOrientation, to initate rotating subviews of viewForBarButtons.

```
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)
```

Rotate subviews: replace self with subview object

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if (animated)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    }

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, degreesToRadians(180)); 

    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, degreesToRadians(90));  

    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, degreesToRadians(-90));
    else 
        self.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    if (animated)
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: But if I change the origin of view then its subviews gets disturb.

Comment: there could be one possibility. create a parent view with size (only padding needed for all side than the viewForBarButtons) and add the viewForBarButtons to it. Set the desired auto resizing mask for the viewForBarButton. Add the superview to the contatiner and resize to the whole view(dont forget to set flexible height and width). This should work.

Comment: I have commented that it would be "previous positionson other sides during orientation change". it would consider the case based on the positions based on the superview to which it has been added. Apologies for prior mistake.

Comment: But I used this viewForBarButtons in my all other controllers. Also the subview for this view are buttons & for most cases the buttons are changed. So how I achieve this.

Comment: I design viewForBarButtons & on viewDidLoad add it to the self.view. and handles its autoresizing mask as I explain in my question. If I set its x & y points then it works correctly but I want to rotate its subviews also.